# i install mcrypt but it says : "mcrypt extension is required"

Tags: centos, mcrypt

i use Centos6 . I want to install mcrypt . I try

```
yum install php-mcrypt
```

and its installed. when i try again it says :

```
    yum install php-mcrypt
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www7.atomicorp.com
 * base: ftp.dgn.net.tr
 * epel: mirror.vit.com.tr
 * extras: ftp.dgn.net.tr
 * remi: remi.schlundtech.de
 * remi-php55: remi.schlundtech.de
 * remi-php56: remi.schlundtech.de
 * remi-test: remi.schlundtech.de
 * updates: ftp.dgn.net.tr
Setting up Install Process
Package php-mcrypt-5.6.0-0.6.beta1.el6.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

but on my webpage :

```
mcrypt extension is required
```

and on phpinfo it is not

How can i solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try:

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
```

Comment: Are you sure about you can run php5enmod on a CentOS 6?

Comment: You can't run php5enmod on CentOS 6.